# Move order summary in checkout

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout

This is my current checkout page:
[image]

I want to move Order Summary area above Shipping Address. I try to add this code

`<move element="sidebar" destination="steps" before="shipping-step"/>`

in **checkout_index_index.xml** but it doesn't work. Is there any way I can do to move the summary area?

Comment: Have you applied below solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can display sidebar block just before Shipping Address.

Add below code to

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary</item>
                                                <!--<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">summary</item>-->
                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/summary</item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/totals</item>
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/summary/totals</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- sort order for this totals is configured on admin panel-->
                                                            <!-- Stores->Configuration->SALES->Sales->General->Checkout Totals Sort Order -->
                                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/subtotal</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cart Subtotal</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
                                                                    <item name="notCalculatedMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Not yet calculated</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="itemsBefore" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge your components here -->
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/cart-items</item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details</item>
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="thumbnail" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail</item>
                                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before_details</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/subtotal</item>
                                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after_details</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>

                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="itemsAfter" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge your components here -->
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

Apply and check it from your end.

Comment: Accept my answer if really solve your problem.